# couchdb mobilefuton pouchdb

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I want to be able to enter data into an android phone phone through the browser using jquery mobile or other? Then want it to sync to a PC database later for querying. I looked at couchdb for other applications a couple of years ago and got on with futon etc fine. I wondered whether it was up to the problem I'm trying to solve now. So far found mobilefuton, android mobilefuton and pouchdb.
Is mobilefuton a web app or is data stored locally? Will not have net connection at point of data entry. I don't want to code in java so guess android mobile futon out. pouchdb looks promising.

Any thoughts?

Forgive me for saying there seems to be an apparent lack of documentation / examples for some of the above. Maybe it's just the level I'm coming at it.

Any pointers much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Mobile Futon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mainerror.mobilefuton) is a [*CouchApp*](http://couchapp.org/page/index). It resides in the Couchbase instance on the device and is served from it to the WebView.

To answer your question. You won't need a data connection to use Mobile Futon even though it is a kind of *web app*.

Now to PouchDB. Here is a short cite of [Dale Harvey's](http://arandomurl.com/) article [*Why PouchDB? CouchDB in the browser*](http://arandomurl.com/2012/03/27/pouchdb-is-couchdb-in-the-browser.html) describing it in short.

> [PouchDB](https://github.com/mikeal/pouchdb) is a Portable CouchDB, it is a near complete implementation of [Apache CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) that runs natively in the browser using [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB) as its storage mechanism, it has the same data model as CouchDB, the same conflict resolution and most importantly, it replicates with CouchDB.